# Need script to tell me when it pops up: Windows Security popup / login prompt box for Exchange/Outlook

Tags: outlook, popup, exchange-server, windows-authentication, prompt

We have the occasional issue where a user gets an Outlook login prompt box to authenticate when there are Exchange connectivity issues.  Users don't like to report it so I would like to create a script to tell me when a user got the pop-up box when attempting to use Outlook connecting to our Exchange.

This is the box we get:
[Windows Security Outlook popup login prompt box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wmv2J.png)

I can easily create a batch script to send info to a text file but there are no traces in the Windows Registry or system that I know of when this box pop-ups up.  I've ran tools such as Sysinternals Process Monitor but I have seen no indication anywhere when this box pops up, so I can't create a script to alert me when it does.  There are some inner-workings of windows authentication and API that i'm missing.

Any ideas or any place I can look to find when this pop-up has occurred? Let me know if i'm asking in the right place.  Any help is appreciated.

Note:  I am not an Exchange admin, just a proactive desktop support person.

Comment: Welcome to _StackOverflow_ ! First, here's the [MCVE page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), describing what a question should contain (I'm talking here about the _existing_ code that doesn't do what it's supposed to). Second, I don't know either how to do it from batch; I think of an program that always runs and continously (e.g. every 5 seconds) iterates the existing windows on screen, and if it finds the Outlook popup (based on type, title, parent, ...), takes some action. [EnumWindows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497(v=vs.85).aspx) could be your answer.

Comment: CristiFati, thank you for your response.   That suggestion sounds like a good idea but I wouldn't know how to even begin doing that in c++ using Windows.  WMIC and vbscript was something I was thinking about since it's native to Windows.  I'm gonna have to research if your suggestion (iterating existing windows) is possible using native Windows tools.

Answer (score 0):

There is no event that you can record. BTW, this is not a security dialog (which in Outlook says "A program is trying..."), this is a credentials prompt.

What is the relevant snippet of your code that causes the prompt?

Comment: You are correct.  This is a credentials prompt, with "Windows Security" as the title on the prompt.  I'm not sure of the snippet of code that causes the prompt since this is the inner-workings of Windows.  When you open Outlook it pops up this prompt asking to authenticate to Exchange.  Let me know if you need more info.  Thanks.

Comment: So it is displayed when the users start Outlook, not when you run your code? Note that SO is for programming questions.

Comment: Exactly, Dmitry. It is displayed when the user starts Outlook, not when running code.  I used Stack Overflow because I thought it might be possible to get an answer using possibly WMIC, vbscript or something native to Windows.  User CristiFati pointed me towards something interesting but I wouldn't know how to even begin creating something like that in c++.  Should this question go in Server Fault or somewhere else?  Thanks for your input.

Comment: The prompt will be not be displayed if the user runs as the domain user who owns the mailbox. Is it displayed for your users because the run as local (not domain) users or because their credentials change/expire?

Comment: It is displayed for a variety of reasons.  It could be cause of what you mentioned and also network connectivity issues between the Outlook client and Exchange server.  What i'm trying to figure out is how I can be notified when it does pop up, no matter the reason it popped up.

Comment: If you were looking for a programming solution, I'd suggest that you write an Outlook COM addin in C++ or Delphi (I don't think .Net would work) and hook the CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentialsW and CredUIPromptForCredentialsW Windows API functions from credui.dll.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry for your suggestion.  It sounds like a good idea but it's way over my head.  Do you think we should move this question to Serverfault or Superuser for a native Windows solution?

Comment: I don't think there is any other solution.